# powershell: concatenate an extension to each element of an array

Tags: powershell

Let's say I used Get-ChildItem and get

```
$list1

Name
----
test1
test2
```

I want an array of list2

```
test1.txt
test2.txt
```

I tried

```
$list2 = % {$list1.name + ".txt"}
```

But as for me list2 content is same as list1 ?

Comment: The linked duplicate shows various effective solutions. To fix your attempt: `$list2 = $list1 | % { $_.name + '.txt' }`